# investigate jvm high cpu usage

Tags: java, jvm, cpu-usage, stack-trace

I have got a jvm process that constantly consumes single cpu core. I checked java threads and there seems to be no running operations, so it seems that load is from native thread.

I tried to use pstack: `pstack <thread_id>`, but it returned me list of addresses which is not very helpful:

```
#0  0x00007fcc33c2b694 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007fcc3011f540 in ?? ()
#2  0x00007fcc2c032710 in ?? ()
#3  0x00007fcc3011f560 in ?? ()
#4  0x00007fcc33c6eaa0 in ?? ()
#5  0x00007fcc3011f560 in ?? ()
#6  0x00007fcc3011f7f0 in ?? ()
#7  0x00007fcc346414d0 in ?? ()
#8  0x00007fcc34641bf8 in ?? ()
#9  0x00007fcc3011f570 in ?? ()
#10 0x00007fcc33c83618 in ?? ()
#11 0x00007fcc3011f5a0 in ?? ()
#12 0x00007fcc33c6ea66 in ?? ()
#13 0x00000006b73ce4b0 in ?? ()
#14 0x00007fcc3011f7f0 in ?? ()
```

What can I do next? As I understand that could be helpful to use symbols to convert adddresses to readable names, but I am not sure if they exist for jvm.

Another option is to ask jvm to print internal state, but I am not sure if such commands exist.

Any information is appreciated.

I am using 1.7.0_80 jdk:

```
# ./java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

within docker (1.9.1) container:

```
# uname -a
Linux 259307ada273 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Mar 6 11:36:42 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: can you profile your process? 10 seconds snapshot will be enough to detect if there's a method that is constantly running

Answer (score 2):

You can try to activate CPU profiling in jvisualvm, see https://visualvm.java.net/profiler.html.

Answer (score 2):

The best free tool which comes with the JVM is Flight Recorder in Mission Control i.e. `jmc` It has much lower overhead, and generally finer detail including the location of object allocations.

If you have high CPU usage, I usually start with object allocation first as this usually yields the quick wins.  Only after the allocation rates have been cleaned up do I look at the CPU profiling.

Java 8 has a better version of Mission Control 5.5, though Java 7 still works ok.

Answer (score 1):

pstack requires symbols, for JITed code they are not available. You can use [jstack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html) instead which acquires the necessary information at runtime.

Besides java-specific profilers - such as jmc, jprofiler or yourkit - linux [perf tools](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) are also an option since they can be use [perf-map-agent](https://github.com/jrudolph/perf-map-agent) to obtain symbols.